# SQL query to populate dropdown field

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to query a table in my DB to populate a dropdown field on a form.
I'd like Field1 as the display and Field2 as the value on my insert.

```
select '[CategoryName]','[CatID]' from BND_ListingCategories
```

The above query just populates [CategoryName] as all values in the dropdown.

Now sure what i'm doing wrong.

---

UPDATE:

Hey guys,
So I think I understand why my query was not working I needed to add a join statement as the (CategoryName) field is on another table.

Even so with this updated query i'm now getting an error
Error: Ambiguous column name 'CatID'.

```
select [CategoryName],[CatID] from BND_ListingCategories
inner join BND_Listing
on BND_ListingCategories.CatID=BND_Listing.CatID
where LID=1
```

---

UPDATE 2

Okay so i'm making progress pulled out the handy ol SQL for dummies.

Fixed my ambiguous problem by editing my query as such.

```
select c.CategoryName, l.CatID
from BND_ListingCategories AS c INNER JOIN BND_Listing as l
on c.CatID = l.CatID
```

Got it working just trying to see how I can SORT alphabetically by CategoryName

Comment: What language are you using? C#/ASP.NET, PHP, something else? You might want to share that code also.

Comment: it's the DNN platform i believe written in C# but i'm using a plug-in for the forms. I'm not sure what it's coded in but i'd guess C# also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the single quotes from column names.

```
select [CategoryName],[CatID] from BND_ListingCategories
```

If you wanted to sort with category name, use ORDER BY.

```
   select c.CategoryName, l.CatID
   from BND_ListingCategories as c 
       INNER JOIN BND_Listing as l
           on c.CatID = l.CatID
    Order by c.CategoryName
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is just a little off thats all. Remove the quotes and you will then return results from your query.

```
select [CategoryName],[CatID] from BND_ListingCategories
```

You should just need to modify the select list to specify the table you want to pull that column from. You may need to do it to both columns in your select statement.

Edit for new updated question:

```
select [CategoryName], BND_Listing.[CatID] from BND_ListingCategories
inner join BND_Listing
on BND_ListingCategories.CatID=BND_Listing.CatID
where LID=1
```

Comment: When i try using that syntax I get an error message.
Failed to initialize form: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

Comment: Can you post all of the code associated with the issue? I have a feeling the issue is earlier in the chain.

Comment: select [CategoryName], BND_ListingCategories.[CatID] from BND_ListingCategories
inner join BND_Listing
on BND_ListingCategories.CatID=BND_Listing.CatID
where LID=1

Comment: You basically just need to add the table in front of the name of the column in the select list to tell the query which table you want to pull that column from. I will edit my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct c.CategoryName, l.CatID
from BND_ListingCategories AS c INNER JOIN BND_Listing as l
on c.CatID = l.CatID
ORDER BY CategoryName ASC
```

This got my dropdown working. Thanks for all your help guys. Got me looking in the right places!